# Python Pandas TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern

Tags: python, pandas, pattern-matching, syntax-error

I am sorry for the super easy question, but I can't make it work

I am cleaning data and want to add a flag, if the name (which is seperate into two columns First and Last Name) is wrong. I established multiple patterns, but for now I was working with seperate statements, can I merge all of those statements into one?

```
pattern = "\?"
match = incremental['First_Name'].str.contains(pattern) | incremental['Last_Name'].str.contains(pattern)
incremental['Name_Flag'] = np.where(match, 'Y', '')

pattern = "tourist"
    match = incremental['First_Name'].str.contains(pattern) | incremental['Last_Name'].str.contains(pattern)
    incremental['Name_Flag'] = np.where(match, 'Y', '')
```

This doesn't work, because the second statement over-writes the first.

```
pattern = ("tourist","/?")
        match = incremental['First_Name'].str.contains(pattern) | incremental['Last_Name'].str.contains(pattern)
        incremental['Name_Flag'] = np.where(match, 'Y', '')
```

I get an error for the second version (not surprisingly)

```
TypeError: first argument must be string or compiled pattern.
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused. Can you add some sample input and expected output? Are you looking to combine the regex pattern? looking to check for both patterns? What is the end-goal question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IF you are trying to look for both regex patterns- as in search for both `?` and `tourist` in the string. you can use the `|` operator. So change `pattern` to

```
pattern = "tourist|\?"
```

This will check if a question mark *OR* if 'tourist` is in the string

If you ever want to check regex, [pythex](https://pythex.org/?regex=tourist%7C%5C%3F&test_string=John%3F%20SMithtourist&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0) is a really good place. I made a test one for you.

Comment: Ph - wow - thank you "pythex" is amazing, wish google would have given me this hours ago ...

Comment: @jeangelj My pleasure. Have fun coding

Comment: something is off with the "?", it is marking everything with a Y

Comment: Test the string in pythex against the regex pattern, see if it matches there. If it does not match, then somewhere else in your code is causing the 'Y'