# Scalable solution for str.contains with list of strings in pandas

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas, dataframe

I am parsing a pandas dataframe `df1` containing string object rows. I have a reference list of keywords and need to delete every row in `df1` containing any word from the reference list.

*Currently, I do it like this:*

```
reference_list: ["words", "to", "remove"]
df1 = df1[~df1[0].str.contains(r"words")]
df1 = df1[~df1[0].str.contains(r"to")]
df1 = df1[~df1[0].str.contains(r"remove")]
```

*Which is not not scalable to thousands of words. However, when I do:*

```
df1 = df1[~df1[0].str.contains(reference_word for reference_word in reference_list)]
```

I yield the error **first argument must be string or compiled pattern**.

*Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45944194/6060083) solution, I tried:*

```
reference_list: "words|to|remove" 
df1 = df1[~df1[0].str.contains(reference_list)]
```

Which doesn't raise an exception but doesn't parse all words eather.

**How to effectively use str.contains with a list of words?**

Comment: When you say "not scaleable", do you mean you would have a bunch of repetitive code? If so, use a loop: `for reference_word in reference_list:`

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6116978/how-to-replace-multiple-substrings-of-a-string) question?

Comment: I'd first join the words and pass them to `str.contains`.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this: `Which doesn't raise an exception but doesn't parse all words eather.`? Can you provide an example that shows that it doesn't work? Because it should.

Comment: @sudonym if you are looking for speed over regex I suggest you to go through Flasktext https://medium.freecodecamp.org/regex-was-taking-5-days-flashtext-does-it-in-15-minutes-55f04411025f for 10000x speed

Comment: Also ensure that your first column is a column of strings. Use `df.iloc[:, 0] = df.iloc[:, 0].astype(str)` if you're not sure.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For a scalable solution, do the following -

1. join the contents of words by the regex OR pipe `|`
2. pass this to `str.contains`
3. use the result to filter `df1`

To index the 0<sup>th</sup> column, don't use `df1[0]` (as this might be considered ambiguous). It would be better to use `loc` or `iloc` (see below).

```
words = ["words", "to", "remove"]
mask = df1.iloc[:, 0].str.contains(r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(words)))
df1 = df1[~mask]
```

Note: This will also work if `words` is a Series.

---

Alternatively, if your 0<sup>th</sup> column is a column of words only (not sentences), then you can use `df.isin`, which should be faster -

```
df1 = df1[~df1.iloc[:, 0].isin(words)]
```

Comment: @sudonym You're welcome. Did you use contains or isin?

Comment: str.contains, since I have sentences in iloc[:,0]

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ we should try to post an answer using `flashtext` it sounds promising.

Comment: @Dark Maybe... but I don't think that's designed to work with pandas.

Comment: May I ask, what does this mean? r'\b(?:{})\b'

Comment: @ahbon I am inserting your search phrases inside a capturing group. I only want full words to be matched.