# Remove items from dataframe faster

Tags: python, pandas

I have a fairly large data frame from which I need to remove values. I currently use this code:

```py
for sha in shas:
        df = df[~df['SHA256'].str.contains(sha, regex=False)]
```

However, this doesn't scale well if shas gets sufficiently large.
Is there a more efficient and faster way to drop elements from a dataframe?

Comment: How about `df[~df['SHA256'].str.contains('|'.join(shas), regex=True)]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use isin() method rather than looping through.

```
df = df[~df['SHA256'].isin(shas)]
```

Edit: This solution only applies with values having an exact match. If you want a solution for values containing some other value, than check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47937697/scalable-solution-for-str-contains-with-list-of-strings-in-pandas)